# Cleaning half-downloaded docker image

Tags: docker, windows-container

I have just installed Docker for Windows and I am running on Windows Container mode.

I downloaded this image `microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express`, which is pretty sizable, and the download gets interrupted halfway.

Where should I look for half-downloaded image and what is the best way to clean it.

`docker image --all` shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker image prune` to remove unused images.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/

Comment: This gave me `total reclaimed space: 0B` which is not what I expected because at least 2 GB have been downloaded

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to dangling layers:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)
```

Comment: `docker image prune` should do that under the covers.